# Numpy convolve: comparing step and impulse responses

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, convolution

I am new to digital signal processing and while developing my first model-based control approach I was faced with the need to compute a convolution for the first time outside any school context (my background being another domain of numerical simulation). I adapted the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139361/python-convolution-with-step-response) to my problem, for which I empirically know the step time response and all fits great. I understand the need to multiply the `impulse_response` from my system by the time step with no difficulty.

```
tend = 600.0  # Total time [s]
dt = 15.0     # Time step [s]
k = 0.01      # Time constant [s]
sp = 0.15     # Step height [a.u.]

# Time interval
t = np.arange(0, tend + 1, dt)

# Define step function.
H = np.ones_like(t)
H[0] = 0.5

def impulse_response(t):
    """ Unit response. """
    return k * np.exp(-k * t) * H

# Response to step. Multiply by dt in discrete case.
response = np.convolve(H, impulse_response(t) * dt, 'full')
response = response[:len(response)//2]

# Define new, longer, time array for plotting response - must 
# be same length as response, with step dt
tp = np.arange(len(response)) * dt

t = np.arange(-tend, tend, dt)
Hp = sp * np.ones_like(t)
Hp[t < 0] = 0.0

plt.style.use('bmh')
plt.step(t, Hp, label='Unit step function')
plt.plot(tp, sp * response, label='Response')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Response [a.u.]')
plt.xlim(-100, tend + 1)
plt.legend()
```

The only point I do not understand in the above code is why do I get different results if I do not multiply by `H` in the function below (as stated in the reference answer and from my understanding, since my step height is zero for t<0, this should make no difference).

```
def impulse_response(t):
    """ Unit response. """
    return k * np.exp(-k * t) * H
```

My problem: in the actual application to a dynamical system I will have arbitrary signals for which the convolution will need to be computed. In order to make sure I understood well the problem statement and to validate the next steps in the development, I tried to check how would this function for a single unit delta impulse. The time-length of such delta is zero, I believe this is the origin of why I do not need to multiply by `dt` in the single impulse case. Is this right? By doing so I get the analytical solution as expected but I do not feel confident with my conclusion. Here follows the modified code.

```
# Define impulse function.
d = np.zeros_like(t)
d[0] = 1.0

def impulse_response(t):
    """ Unit response. """
    return k * np.exp(-k * t)

# Response to impulse. Multiply by dt in discrete case.
response = np.convolve(d, impulse_response(t), 'full')
response = response[:len(response)//2]

# Define new, longer, time array for plotting response - must 
# be same length as response, with step dt
tp = np.arange(len(response)) * dt

plt.style.use('bmh')
plt.plot(tp, response, label='Response')
plt.plot(tp, k * np.exp(-k * tp), label='Analytical')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Response [a.u.]')
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually with a convolution the kernel (your impulse_response) is some rather small thing compared to the array it is applied on. Maybe 3, 5, or 9 elements wide. Of course depending on the case!

In your case it seems to be half as long as the array, right?

My guess is, that in your case the results are problably not the same, but so similar that you don't notice. The huge kernel "smears" (or averages) everything over.

Comment: Thank you. From your comment I understand that I'd better make the pulse 2-time-point wide so that it will provide the physical output. I just illustrated with a half-array size window, but it could be much less (I am simulating a time-delayed response of 300s over varying prediction horizons).